# logstash on docker: set multiple pipeline

Tags: docker, logstash, logstash-configuration

I am using [this elastic search stack](https://github.com/deviantony/docker-elk) on docker. I want to be able to run multiple logstash instance since logstash instance [does not support multiple pipeline](https://github.com/elastic/logstash/issues/6521)

how to do that? Is it possible to run multiple instance in the same docker container?

Thanks!

Comment: You can run multiple container instance of the same image. Or you can try with swarm.